# Making JDOM dynamic to add new elements

Tags: java, jdom

I'm trying to make this code more dynamic by not adding a new student and writing `Element eltFirstName = new Element("FirstName");` and lastname several times, anyway to achieve through a for loop without using sax.

```
public class javaForm extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        Element eltRoot = new Element("Students");

        Element eltStudent = new Element("Student");
        Element eltFirstName = new Element("FirstName");
        eltFirstName.addContent("Mike");
        Element eltLastName = new Element("LastName");
        eltLastName.addContent("dan");

        eltStudent.addContent(eltFirstName);
        eltStudent.addContent(eltLastName);

        eltRoot.addContent(eltStudent);

        Document doc = new Document(eltRoot);
        XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
        String xml = outputter.outputString(doc);
        resp.setContentType("application/xml");
        resp.getWriter().println(xml);

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to build a student object:

```
public class Student{

String firstName;
String lastName;

public Student(String firstName, String lastName){
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getFirstName(){
return firstName;
}
public String getLastName(){
return lastName;
}
}
```

Afterwards I would make a `StudentWritter class` wich creates a list with your `Student objects` and prints them:

```
class StudentWritter{

List<Student> listOfStudents;

public StudentWritter(){
  getAllStudents();
}

public List<Student> getAllStudents(){

  ArrayList<Student> listOfStudents= new ArrayList<>();
  while(thereAreStudents){ // I dont know were you get them from :P
    Student aStudent = new Student(firstName, lastName); //makes a Student object
    listOfStudents.add(aStudent); // adds a Student to the List
  }
  this.listOfStudents = listOfStudents; 
}

//afterwards initialise your outputer and print the list :D
public void printStudents(HttpServletResponse resp){
  Document doc = new Document("Students"); //creates a document "Students"
  XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
  resp.setContentType("application/xml"); 

  for(Student aStudent : listOfStudents){
      String outputString = aStudent.getFirstName() + " " + aStudent.getLastName() 
      resp.getWriter().println(outputString);
  }
}
```

If you now initialise your `StudentWritter class` all your Students will be stored into an `ArrayList<Student>`because the method `getAllStudents()` is in the `constructor` of the `class`. That means if you want to print all students instanciate the `StudentWritter class` and resolve your `printStudents()` method:

```
StudentWritter studentWritter = new StudentWritter(); //you will have to change to constructor to your needs
studentwritter.printStudents();
```

Im sorry for all the typos, Iam working without an IDE right now and would appreciate an editor.